# How to change the path from "specialfolders(16)" to an XYZ folder on C drive?

Tags: vba, outlook

The code below saves the attachments [*to "My Documents" folder*] of "selected" emails in Outlook.

Can you please advise how to change the location of the `sFolderPath = objWSCript.specialfolders(16)` to a "New Folder" folder on C drive ?

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveAttchFiles()

Dim olMail As MailItem
Dim olAtchs As Attachments
Dim olSelection As Selection
Dim iCount As Long, i As Long
Dim sFolderPath As String, sFilePath As String, sDeletedFiles As String
Dim objWSCript As Object

On Error Resume Next

Set objWSCript = CreateObject("WSCript.Shell")

sFolderPath = objWSCript.specialfolders(16)

Set olSelection = ActiveExplorer.Selection

sFolderPath = sFolderPath & "\New Folder\"

For Each olMail In olSelection

Set olAtchs = olMail.Attachments
iCount = olAtchs.Count
sDeletedFiles = ""

If iCount > 0 Then
For i = iCount To 1 Step -1
sFilePath = sFolderPath & olAtchs.Item(i).FileName
olAtchs.Item(i).SaveAsFile sFilePath

Next i
End If


Next olMail

Door:

Set objWSCript = Nothing
Set olAtchs = Nothing
Set olSelection = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: `sFolderPath = "C:\myfolder\"`

Comment: ..as in, you want to **create** a new folder, or is the folder **called** "New Folder"?

Comment: or do you want to pick a folder from a dialog box?

Comment: @ACatInLove - your solution is not working

Comment: @ashleedawg the folder is called "New Folder"

Comment: What is the whole path?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook "dialog box"? I want to simply save them in e.g.drive C:\All Folders\New Folder

Comment: @ashleedawg C:\All Folders\New Folder\

Comment: In that case it's just as @ACatInLove commented.  Just thought I'd throw the idea out there of being able to pick the folder if it's likely to be a different folder each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Really?***  You have a folder called **New Folder**?  And it's in another folder called **All Folders**?  *boy oh boy*....

Anyhow, if that's really the case then you only need to change:

```
sFolderPath = sFolderPath & "\New Folder\"
```

...to...

```
sFolderPath = "C:\All Folders\New Folder\"
```

---

As a bonus, check out:

- [Getting Organized: Great Tips for Better File Names](https://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2385613,00.asp)
- [Best practices for file naming](http://library.stanford.edu/research/data-management-services/data-best-practices/best-practices-file-naming)

Comment: Haha (it was a dummy example - but then you knew that anyway) Worked perfectly mate. Much obliged!

Comment: Oh thank goodness.  No I didn't know that.  People never cease to amaze.  For all I know, you're changing the folder name right _now_!  :-)  Thanks.  *--John Doe*

Comment: :D "People never cease to amaze." <<< I agree completely. Thanks and Happy New Year!